# Vue2Js: Is it possible to call a method with attributes from one component in another?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 3 Components: Component 1 is Top Menu, Component 2 is a kind of lib with functions, Component 3 is main code.

Ideally, I want to use in Component 1 a method from Component 2 with attributes from Component 3.
And then use Component 1 in Component 3.

```js
// Component 1 Top Menu
Vue.component('component1', {
    props: {
        titleTest: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        textTest: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    template: `
    <div>
        <div :title="titleTest">{{ titleTest }}</div>
        <div :data-test="textTest">{{ textTest }}</div>
        <button id='test' type="submit" @click="bar">TestButton</button>
    </div>
    `,
    created() {
        console.log('Created1');
        this.$root.$refs.component1 = this;
    },
    methods: {
        //alertText should be passed from Component 3
        bar: function(alertText) {
            console.log(alertText);
            this.$root.$refs.component2.foo(alertText);
        }
    }
});

// Component 2 Lib
Vue.component('component2', {
    created() {
        this.$root.$refs.component2 = this;
    },
    methods: {
        foo: function(alertText) {
            alert('this is component2.foo' + alertText);
        }
    }
});

// Component 3 Main Code
Vue.component('component3', {
    template: `
    <div>
        <div>Some text</div>
        <ul>
            <li>List Item1</li>
            <li>List Item2</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <component1 ref="component1" :title-test="test1" :text-test="test2"></component1>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
    data: function() {
        return {
            test1: 'testText1',
            test2: 'testText2',
            alertText: 'alertText'
        };
    },
    created: function() {
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#plotlyExample',
});
```

I am not really sure is it possible, tried with "emits" but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Vue.component('component2', {...})`, it just tels Vue about named component, and that does not make component instance, for using methods of `component2` it should be rendered/mounteded. But i think, you wrong using `component2`, for same, will be better using mixins or provide/reject or vuex.

Comment: Well here yeah the second is unimportant but in the reality it serves as a storage for functions.  I will check mixins thanks!